# Android read html files anywhere in the external storage through intent

Tags: android, file

I'm new to Android programing. I'm creating a small app which can test the html files that stored in external memory. The path will be different. I need to read them from the options recent, documents, download and etc. is it possible ?

Comment: how about trying it out 1st?

Comment: I'm building this app to give my clients. So the location depends.

Comment: Of course it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
          public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/";
      songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String mp3Pattern = ".html";
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                       String foldername= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "foldername";
                       String filepath= file.getAbsolutePath();

                        if(!foldername.equals(filepath)){

                        scanDirectory(file);
                        }
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }
```

Comment: give your sd card path and get all html files stored in sd card

Comment: Thanks. i will try and tell you. What does the rootpath means?. the html file maybe inside any folder in sdcard. The app need to use intent to read file

Comment: means which place you want to find your  storage location

Comment: it may be emulator/0/sdcard/------- like this

Comment: Yes. but when i read a file from documents or download it only showing like documents/file.html ..not the exact path

Comment: what you want you want list of html files in your device or read all html files

Comment: first get path of external storage give to this method and make list or recylerview show list of html file on click call webview in android

Comment: this method will give you only just file name and path you have to code for read in webview

Comment: Yes i have code. And i use intent to select files . but the problem occurs when the client select files download or documents

Comment: you r using intent so you have to pass file path whith file name to any browser like crom

Comment: i not getting the proper file path for webview when client open the files through documents, download or recents option in intent

Comment: don't use intent open in your app is good attach webview its 3 line code run on that its easy

Comment: showing this when i use intent result and pass to webview 'file:///document/primary:folder name/file.html file not found'

Comment: you r very new in android you will get different path like storage/0/foldername/

Comment: I'm not getting that when i took file from document or recent or download options in intent

Comment: now you have every thing just  now if you have knowledge of java call method getplaylist it will return ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>of html files.

Comment: I had modified just copy past